# How play/pause all animation css with components React.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have created several CSS animations in my React.js project

I'm looking to put a general button to pause them if the user wants, because they can disturb or simply slow down the pc.

I have done this by targeting classes but it doesn't work at all :

Button.js :

```js
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

function Button() {

    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
       
        const el2 = ref.current;
        console.log(el2);
    
        const jstoggle = document.getElementById('js-toggle');
        console.log(jstoggle)

        jstoggle.addEventListener('click', () => {

            const animations = document.querySelectorAll('.person-name', '.background-penny');
            animations.forEach(animation => {
                const running = animation.style.animationPlayState || 'running';
                animation.style.animationPlayState = running === 'running' ? 'paused' : 'running';
            })
    
        });

      }, []);
    

   

    return (
        <>
        <button id="js-toggle" ref={ref} className="btn" type="button">PAUSE ANIMATION</button>
        </>

    );

}

export default Button
```

Animations CSS :

```css
.person-name{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -225deg,
    #231557 0%,
    #44107a 29%,
    #ff1361 67%,
    #fff800 100%
  );
  background-size: auto auto;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: textclip 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
      font-size: 19px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

@keyframes textclip {
  to {
    background-position: 200% center;
  }
}
```

```css
.background-penny{
  padding: 20px;
  animation: changecolor 3s infinite;
  transition: none;
}
```

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me only difference is i have attached onClick event handler to button.

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    const animations = document.querySelectorAll('.person-name', '.background-penny');
    animations.forEach(animation => {
            const running = animation.style.animationPlayState || 'running';
            animation.style.animationPlayState = running === 'running' ? 'paused' : 'running';
        })
  }

<button id="js-toggle" onClick={()=>handleClick()} ref={ref} className="btn" type="button">PAUSE ANIMATION</button>
```

Can you also check if changecolor animation is correctly implemented, textclip animation is working correctly.

Comment: thank for your answer ! this working for the first animation '.person-name' but doesn't work for '.background-penny'

Comment: when i change order in querySelectorAll , background works but not .person-name

Comment: ('.person-name', '.background-penny') i change that to that : ('.person-name , .background-penny') , and it's working ! thank you very much for your help !!

Comment: the only problem will be to put the animation on "before" or "after", it does not work like that